# List all primes up to 100

Tags: c#, primes

Written the below code trying to identify all primes up 100. It's outputting 1,2 and 5. Can anyone see any reason why it wouldn't continue past the first 3?

I know there's some efficiency tweaks I can do (only odds numbers etc) but just trying to get the core (overkill) concept down first. I'm a complete noob just trying to enhance my intuition with programming so I know it's probably not the most elegant solution but more interested in why it doesn't work.

Appreciate any help.. HAPPY NEW YEAR!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int q = 100;
    for (int i = 1; i < q; i++)
    {
        if ((q % i) == 0)
        {
            bool isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
            {
                if ((i % j) == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime == true)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(i + " is a prime number... hopefully.");
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey()
}
```

Comment: Set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect your variables.

Comment: Note: 1, 2, and 5 are not the first three prime numbers...

Comment: What's `if ((q % i) == 0)` doing?

Comment: 3 is also prime, by the way

Comment: You are pretty close, but that first if statement is where you set your breakpoint and actually watch what is happening.

Comment: What if you want to find all primes up to a larger number like 100000? It would be better to use parallel LINQ in this scenario. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060352/why-this-prime-number-finding-code-is-producing-different-results-over-iteration/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`q%i` filters the results to prime factors of 100, which are 1, 2, 5

If you remove that portion, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you my friend that solved it immediately. I'm not 100% sure why lol so I'm going to stare at this for a few hours.

My intention was to check if it's a factor of 100 and then proceed to check if that factor was prime.